# Vibration absorber design: free body diagram of a mass-spring system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

Trying to draw the free body diagram of this, any help would be appreciated.
The $y$ is the amplitude of vibration of ground. Up is the positive direction.

[image: diagram of proposed design]

Comment: It's a basic tuned mass damper. The resonant frequency of the absorber will be set to the dominant frequency of the machine. The absorber will vibrate at its tuned frequency and those vibrations will not be transmitted to the structure.

Comment: @DLS3141 How do I calculate the tuned frequency?

Comment: Typically k >> k_absorber so f_n of the absorber is sqrt(k_absorber/m_absorber)

Comment: @DLS3141 Just to confirm f_n natural frequency right?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dynamic+vibration+absorber&safe=active&client=ms-android-htc-rev&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji1d7vpa_LAhWIcRQKHb2aDzwQ_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=511#imgrc=xJBTcMOdNxJibM%3A                                                                  am I going for the middle image of this gif?

Comment: f_n = natural frequency

Comment: Hi Robot_enthusiast, welcome to Engineering SE. We are not really a general homework help site or a discussion forum - we ask for focused questions with broadly applicable solutions. Please check out some of our [help] articles and consider an [edit] to the question to make it more reasonably scoped.

Answer (score 1):

- Isolate $m_\text{absorber}$. Following forces need to be introduced:

  - gravity $m_\text{absorber}g$
  - spring force $k_\text{absorber}(x_1-x_2)$
- Isolate $m$. Following forces need to be introduced:

  - gravity $mg$
  - spring force $k_\text{absorber}(x_2-x_1)$
  - spring force $k(x_2-y)$

Make sure to pay attention at the sign of the spring forces: depending on their orientation, you might need the opposite of the expressions mentioned above.

Comment: Awesome thank you, definitely cleared up a couple of things

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that maximum static deflection is as follows:

Comment: ((m +m.absorber)g)/k +k.absorber

Comment: am I correct about the static deflection?